# How do I run Yardoc Server via Passenger?

Tags: ruby, passenger, rack

I know that I can use ProxyPass to serve up my `yardoc server` instance but since `yard` uses Rack, shouldn't it be possible to run `yard` via Passenger?

How would I go about setting this up? [The Passenger Docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application) describe a public directory and a config.ru for Rack apps, but they're not available in Yardoc's source.

Comment: Looks that this [guide](http://chrismdp.github.com/2010/03/multiple-ci-joes-with-rack-and-passenger/) has the best solution for cijoe, which has the same issues as I describe with yardoc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yard does not provide a convenience Rack integration AFAIK, but it features a rack adapter that allows you to run it inside a Rack Server like Passenger.

You need to write your own `config.ru` to configure Passenger to run a Yard Server using Yard's `RackAdapter` class. Also you need to tell Yard where it can find the documentation it should serve.

I have not tested this, but here is a rough guess at what the `config.ru` should look like:

```
require "yard/server/rack_adapter"

run YARD::Server::RackAdapter.new({
  "mylib" => [
    YARD::Server::LibraryVersion.new("mylib", "1.0", "/path/to/mylib/.yardoc")
  ]
})
```

Where `mylib` is the name of the library you want to serve.

See here:

- [RackAdapter](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/0.7.4/YARD/Server/RackAdapter)
- [LibraryVersion](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/0.7.4/YARD/Server/LibraryVersion)